# How to push text from html input into AngularJS array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, forms, input

I'm new to AngularJS - trying to build a pretty vanilla todo-list app.
I can't figure out how to push the text value from the input box into the 'todos' array.

Here's my code.

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="main">
        <p>Todo App</p>
        <input ng-model="todoList" type="text" name="input" placeholder="Enter tasks here">
        <button ng-click="addTodo()">Add</button>
        <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
            {{todo}
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.todos = []
  $scope.todoList = "";

  $scope.addTodo = function(){
    $scope.todos.push($scope.todoList)
  }

  $scope.clearAll = function(){
    $scope.todos = []
  }


});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the problem? Your code works fine! - [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/byw7kLuq/)
Just `}` is missing in `{{ todo }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's just a typo in your template, try

```
{{todo}}
```

instead of

```
{{todo}
```

Everything else looks fine

Here is completed code: http://plnkr.co/edit/tRGw9UTRVhXvD51lxYjF?p=preview

I've also added track by $index statement to allow duplicated todos.

Comment: Cheers, can't believe I missed that. Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do here? Would wrapping the input element in a form be a good practice to get into?

Comment: In my opinion - no. I'm think, forms semantically is containers for multiple inputs, related to one entity. Also form is used when you want to post/put something to the server without javascript. So I think there is no need to wrap single input to form.

Comment: @user3315570 Why would you wrap it in a form if there is no use for it? Keep it simple. Als I have modified a fiddle from the comments and added this line to ng-repeat: `track by $index` because from Angular 1.2 and up it does not allow duplicates in arrays, so you have to track it with the index. https://jsfiddle.net/byw7kLuq/1/

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the module "plunker".
You have to use ng-app to include the module.\

The updated and working code is

```
HTML

<div class="container" data-ng-app="plunker" >
  <div class="main" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Todo App</p>
    <input ng-model="todoList" type="text" name="input" placeholder="Enter tasks here">{{todoList}}
    <button ng-click="addTodo()">Add</button>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        {{todo}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker',[]);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.todos = []
$scope.todoList = "";
$scope.addTodo = function(){
  $scope.todos.push($scope.todoList)
}
$scope.clearAll = function(){
  $scope.todos = []
 }
});
```

Hope it helps!!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can write this just to debug it a big

```
$scope.addTodo = function(todo) {
    // console.log(todo)
    $scope.todos.push(todo);
    // console.log($scope.todos)
}
```

in your template, call

```
<input ng-model="todo" // (not todoList)
<button ng-click="addTodo(todo)"> // (todo is local here)
```

one way to help yourself is do the following

1. use lot of console, everyone is newbie once, just use tons of them until you understand the workflow
2. use local variable, global variable is always confusing, even to a Pro.